# How to setup TLS certificates for a Windows gitlab-runner?

Tags: windows, ssl, gitlab

I've been trying to use this [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html) as guide but I am having no luck setting up a gitlab-runner on Windows.  It correctly polls for jobs but when it tries to pull artifacts, it returns a `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` error.

Can anyone step through how to generate the proper certificate and attach it to the Windows gitlab-runner in order to get things to work?

I've tried generating certificates using openssl and setting the `--tls-ca-file` flag but so far, it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working finally using [this](https://holdmybeersecurity.com/2021/02/19/devops-tales-install-setup-gitlab-gitlab-runners-on-docker-windows-linux-and-macos/) as a reference.

The basic idea, when you're not hosting your own gitlab server, is to pull the certificate from gitlab.com.  From your browser, click on the little lock symbol next to the `https://gitlab.com` URL and download the certificate.  From Safari, it's just dragging the little certificate image over to your Desktop.

Once you have the cert, store it in your Gitlab-Runner folder and reference it with the `tls-ca-file` parameter in your `config.toml`.